# Confused with the biasing pins for this laser diode

Tags: diodes, laser

If I want to DC bias the following laser diode it seems I need to use pin 3 with a current source (drawn in red by me) as follows:

[image]

Description of the pies are shown below:

[image]

There is no anode pin nor a ground pin.

The thing is, RF is the modulation input. But there are no dedicated pins for biasing. Let's say I connected the RF connector for modulation input. How will I then connect the bias current source?

[image]

edit:

[image]

Comment: Your diagram shows pin 3 as connected to an internal inductor. The specs show pin 3 going to the diode cathode. Which is correct?

Comment: They just call it cathode. The diagram is correct.

Comment: Then there is a separate RF modulation connector, **and** pin 3, with internal inductor for DC bias? What is your question?

Comment: Pin 3 is a "dedicated pin for biasing".

Answer (score 1):

> But there are no dedicated pins for biasing.

Pin 3 is a dedicated pin for biasing.

> How will I then connect the bias current source?

That depends on the design of the bias current source.

It's somewhat likely that the current source would be connected to some negative power supply circuit, and that power supply circuit would need to be referenced to the RF ground.

Comment: Hello thank you for the answer. I made some drawings to be sure here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cx2zV.png I understand what you mean in the case of a voltage resistor current source as in Figure 1. But if I use a current source module as in Figure 2 how will be the connections? Positive terminal of the power input will be connected again to the RF ground? Where will the LD- terminal be connected?

Comment: @ty_1917, can you share the datasheet for the current source?

Comment: The one I have is here 5A version: https://www.teamwavelength.com/download/Datasheets/pld10k-ch.pdf

Comment: @ty_1917, follow figure 8 in that datasheet. For the laser diode's anode use the case of your laser module, for the cathode use pin 3. Don't connect the ground of your power supply (shown as "5 VDC" in figure 8) to the laser case/rf ground.

Comment: Do you mean this way: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKx0V.png ?

Comment: RF input is coming from a function generator which is earth grounded. I guess in that case the power supply ground of the driver should be isolated from earth correct?